# Conditionally formating colors of tile plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following chart generated using `ggplot2`. I would like to find out how to conditionally format the color of each tile according to the following color hex codes and Value specifications

```
#0a5d00 if Value > 2
#0eff00 if Value > 1 and < 2
#ece75f if Value > 0 and < 1
#e6cc00 if Value > -1 and < 0
#ff0000 if Value > -2 and < -1
#7b0000 if Value < -2
```

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18993, 19024, 19052, 19083, 
19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19266), class = "Date"), Value = c(-3, 
-2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Value, fill = Value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update adding `scale_identity()` thanks to @Tanga94:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(my_color = case_when(
     Value > 2 ~ "#0a5d00", 
     Value > 1 & Value < 2 ~ "#0eff00",
     Value > 0 & Value< 1 ~ "#ece75f",
     Value > -1 & Value < 0 ~ "#e6cc00",
     Value > -2 & Value< -1 ~ "#ff0000", 
     Value < -2 ~ "#7b0000", 
     TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Value, fill = my_color)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Or with `cut` `data %>% mutate(my_color = cut(Value, breaks = c(-Inf, -2.01, -1, 0, 1, 2, Inf ), labels = c("7b0000", "#ff0000", "#e6cc00", "#ece75f", "#0eff00", "#0a5d00"))) %>%  ggplot(aes(Date, Value, fill = my_color)) +
  geom_tile()`

Comment: @akrun. Please post as answer!

Comment: Thanks @TarJae . I think you just had to add ```scale_fill_identity``` to your solution, but otherwise your solution works well